# php copy not working with utf8 characters?

Tags: php

I am using php copy() function and am getting strange results which made me google and couldn't find anything about this topic so my conclusion was that php's copy($src, $dest) function cant have utf8 characters in the $src and $dest, but just wanted you guys to confirm on this - or maybe you know a way around this?

**final conclusion:**
@azat: I thank you for your answers and trying to help - but all in all now I see I was wrong! The files (when downloaded to my computer did have correct caracters!, but when I was viewing the contents of the folder from my WinSCP I was seeing them all scrambled which I presume is because of the WinSCP. Anyway I will mark your answer correct as you were the only one to help and made me realize my error in the end.

**edit:** system on which i run this is Linux and an example of the command in php file is this:

```
<?php
    copy ("images/test.png", "images/myTestŽĆČĐŠžćčđš.png");
?>
```

**edit2:**

```
#>uname -a
Linux litij.avalon.hr 2.6.18-274.3.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Sep 6 20:13:52 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

#>cat /etc/mtab
/dev/root /lib virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /opt virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /lib64 virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/lib virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/lib64 virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/sbin virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/share virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/bin virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/man virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/X11R6 virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/kerberos virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/libexec virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/local/bin virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/local/share virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/local/Zend virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/local/IonCube virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/include virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/local/lib virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /var/spool virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /var/lib virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /var/cpanel virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /var/run virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /var/log virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /tmp virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /dev virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /bin virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /usr/local/apache/domlogs virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /etc/mail virtfs defaults 0 0
/dev/root /home/fotoctim virtfs defaults 0 0
none /proc proc rw 0 0
```

Worth noting is that my copy command doesn't give any errors :(

```
if (copy($src, $dest)){
    echo  "File <b>successfully</b> copied to $dest<br/>";
}
else{
    echo "File <b>was not!</b> copied to $dest<br/>";
}
```

Comment: it's not about 'php's copy() function', you know. But about your operation system.

Comment: So what are the strings you are passing to `copy()` ?

Comment: What OS you have? What filesystem you have?

Comment: @all: I edited the post so please take a look now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext4
LANG=en_US.UTF-8

```
<?
touch("/tmp/test.png");
copy("/tmp/test.png", "/tmp/myTestŽĆČĐŠžćčđš.png");
```

```
azat:~$ ls /tmp/myTestŽĆČĐŠžćčđš.png 
/tmp/myTestŽĆČĐŠžćčđš.png
```

So the question is what filesystem you have and mount options

Comment: thank you for your answer, but can you tell me how can i find out my filesystem and mount options? Btw, I'm on a shared hosting so I don't know if changing some settings will be available to me.

Comment: `cat /etc/mtab`, and post here absolute path. And `uname -a` please

Comment: I updated my OP, please take a look. Btw, as you will see I don't get any errors.

Comment: In this case: maybe your `virtfs` is not support this feature. Could you exec this from console? `touch /tmp/myTestŽĆČĐŠžćčđš.png && ls /tmp/myTestŽĆČĐŠžćčđš.png`

Comment: @szat: seems like you're right, this is what I get:     /tmp/myTest\256\306\310\320\251\276\346\350\360\271.png

Comment: Also try to set `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` or see `locale` command, and the retry `touch && ls`

Comment: I thank you for your answers and trying to help - but all in all now I see I was wrong! The files (when downloaded to my computer did have correct caracters!, but when I was viewing the contents of the folder from my WinSCP I was seeing them all scrambled which I presume is because of the WinSCP.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but you need to check that the format of the php file containing the copy script below is utf-8 format. so when it copies the file, it copies it in the same format. this is how i solved my problem.

```
<?php
```

copy($path,$dest);
?>